# chosen-select creates huge gap after footer

Tags: html, css, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen-select configured for single select with a search box in it. It kind of has a lot of options (in this question limited to 20 options) and it's positioned somewhere down on the page. If you select anything from the select box, it creates a huge gap under the footer.

I think the problem has to do something with these CSS lines:

```
div.content {
    position:absolute;
}

div.filler {
    height:35px;
}
```

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/22/) to demonstrate the problem. The gap in this fiddle, isn't that huge, but in my app it's way bigger than in the fiddle. I was unable to reproduce the same gap. The scroll bar is maybe 10px big after the selection in my app.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your test site ?

Comment: It's not online, I'm developing it local. I don't have a domain name and hosting for it yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the root problem is that you're layout is screwing up when the content overflows but that is another topic. I can give you a quick fix for now.

The chosen dropdown is being created with a `ul.chosen-results`. What you can do is, limit the height of that `ul`

Try and use this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/e62Wu/23/)**

```
.chosen-results{
    max-height:200px !Important; /*Adjust max-height to waht suits you.*/
}
```

Comment: Oh... what exactly is doing the screw up? Could you give me some pointers about that so I can fix it? Tried your solution it seems to work as long as the browser is somewhat maximized.

Comment: Well, for starters you shouldn't use `position:absolute` unless absolutely necessary. There are other ways to achieve. Like for a simple header content footer layout in which footer always stick to the bottom of content and content at least covers full height when there isn't enough content, you can use `calc()`. Here is an [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/fcVPH/) I just created for another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289470/html-css-layout-with-header-two-columns-and-footer/22289678#22289675)

Comment: Well the `position:absolute` was indeed necessary, because if you remove that, you'll see that the `chosen-select` doesn't overflow its parent. And therefore not showing the rest of the options you can select. If there is another way to accomplish this, i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Well then I suggest you change it's position. Open it upwards. how does that sound ?

Comment: Sounds like an option, but suppose I want it open down wards, would you happen to know how to do that too, by not using `position:absolute`?

Comment: Not without seeing your actual site. sorry.